# MassTransit consume non MassTransit message

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a console app that is publishing messages to a RabbitMQ exchange. Is it possible for a subscriber that is built with MassTransit to consume this message?

This is the publisher code:

```
    public virtual void Send(LogEntryMessage message)
    {

        using (var connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            props.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: _endpointConfiguration.Exchange, routingKey: _endpointConfiguration.RoutingKey, basicProperties: null,
                body: body);
        }
    }
```

This is the subscriber code:

```
      IBusControl ConfigureBus()
      {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
                h.Username(username);
                h.Password(password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "LogEntryQueue", e =>
            {
                e.Handler<LogEntryMessage>(context =>
                Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Value was entered: {context.Message.MessageBody}"));
            });
        });
    }
```

This is the consumer code:

```
    public class LogEntryMessageProcessor : IConsumer<LogEntryMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<LogEntryMessage> context)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Value was entered: 
                      {context.Message.Message.MessageBody}");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817998/masstransit-not-consuming-non-masstransit-messages/76882601#76882601

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can get the answer in the [Interoperability](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html) section, in particular look at the [example message](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html#example-message).

Basically, you need to construct a JSON object according to some simple rules.

Example message looks like this:

```
{
    "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/input_queue",
    "headers": {},
    "message": {
        "value": "Some Value",
        "customerId": 27
    },
    "messageType": [
        "urn:message:MassTransit.Tests:ValueMessage"
    ]
}
```

You can easily check how more complex messages look like by creating both publisher and consumer, run the program in order to create bindings, then stop the consumer and publish some messages. They will be in the subscriber queue so you can easily read them using the management plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was able to publish and subscribe but the message processor can't serialize the message. The MassTransit message context was created and it contains the message object but all of the properties of the message are null.

Comment: If you can compose a sample repo on github, I probably can find some time and look at it.

Comment: Thank you! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I created https://github.com/cksanjose/masstransit_pubsub and  https://github.com/cksanjose/masstransit_subscriber. The first one is plain RabbitMQ publisher. The subscriber is MassTransit and RabbitMQ.

Comment: Seems like this https://github.com/cksanjose/masstransit_pubsub/blob/master/CheckBee.DMI.MessagePublisher.LogEntry/Program.cs#L59 should be LogEntryPayload and your consumer should consume that type instead of the outer type which is essentially your version of the MT message envelope.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured that out too. I pulled down the MT source and I was able to debug it.

Comment: Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817998/masstransit-not-consuming-non-masstransit-messages/76882601#76882601

Answer (score 1):

For MassTransit to process a message that is published by non-MassTransit client,
the message has to contain the metadata required by MassTransit as described in the [Interoperability](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html) page.
The consumer of the message has to process the payload of the message.
In the code below, the payload is LogEntryPayload:

```
public class LogEntryMessageProcessor : IConsumer<LogEntryPayload>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<LogEntryPayload> context)
    {
        //var payload = context.GetPayload<LogEntryPayload>();
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Value was entered: {context.Message.Id} - {context.Message.MessageBody}");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```