# Masstransit not consuming non MassTransit messages

Tags: asp.net-core, queue, azureservicebus, producer-consumer, masstransit

I have to publish a message using Python and consume it using MassTransit (.Net core app).

To test, I created a Console Application to produce the messages using the Azure.ServiceBuss library.
The consumer is a MassTransit implementation of the ServiceBus.

When I send the message to the queue (using my console application), MassTransit is not able to consume it.
I am aware of the Interoperability and all the headers we must send in order to MassTransit consume the messages, but I am not able to make the consumer work.

The producer:

```
namespace MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Models.Commands
{
    class Program
    {
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "connstring";
        const string QueueName = "topic";
        static IQueueClient queueClient;

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);

            // Send messages.
            await SendMessagesAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("ENVIOU");
            Console.ReadKey();

            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        private static async Task SendMessagesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommand(
                        NewId.NextGuid(),
                        NewId.NextGuid(),
                        new Proposta()
                        )
                    {
                        Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>() { },
                        Host = new HostInfo()
                    });

                    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

                    Console.WriteLine($"Enviando mensagem: {messageBody}");

                    await queueClient.SendAsync(message);

                    Console.WriteLine("Enviado. Enviar outro?");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} :: Exception: {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class I'm sending:

```
namespace MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Models.Commands
{
    public class EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommand
    {
        public EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommand(Guid msgId, Guid convId, Proposta msg)
        {
            MessageId = msgId.ToString();
            ConversationId = convId.ToString();
            MessageType = new[]
            {
                "urn:message:MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Models.Commands:Proposta"
            };
            Message = msg;
            SourceAddress = "";
            DestinationAddress = "sb://organization.servicebus.windows.net/topic";
        }

        public string DestinationAddress { get; set; }

        public string MessageId { get; set; }

        public string ConversationId { get; set; }

        public string SourceAddress { get; set; }

        public HostInfo Host { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, object> Headers { get; set; }

        public Proposta Message { get; set; }

        public string[] MessageType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Proposta
    {
        public Proposta()
        {
            Nome = "TESTE 2";
            AcaoId = 2;
            Mensagem = "TESTE 2";
        }

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int AcaoId { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    }

    public class HostInfo
    {
        public HostInfo()
        {
            MachineName = "NOTEXXXXX";
            ProcessName = "iisexpress";
            ProcessId = 34188;
            Assembly = "MassTransit.MultipleBus";
            AssemblyVersion = "1.0.0.0";
            FrameworkVersion = "3.1.5";
            MassTransitVersion = "7.0.2.0";
            OperatingSystemVersion = "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19041.0";
        }

        public string MachineName { get; set; }

        public string ProcessName { get; set; }

        public int ProcessId { get; set; }

        public string Assembly { get; set; }

        public string AssemblyVersion { get; set; }

        public string FrameworkVersion { get; set; }

        public string MassTransitVersion { get; set; }

        public string OperatingSystemVersion { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The message queued in ServiceBus:

```
{
    "DestinationAddress": "sb://organization.servicebus.windows.net/topic",
    "MessageId": "00010000-0faa-0009-6939-08d854e183aa",
    "ConversationId": "00010000-0faa-0009-69f0-08d854e183aa",
    "SourceAddress": "",
    "Host": {
        "MachineName": "NOTEXXXXX",
        "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
        "ProcessId": 32608,
        "Assembly": "MassTransit.MultipleBus",
        "AssemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "FrameworkVersion": "3.1.5",
        "MassTransitVersion": "7.0.2.0",
        "OperatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19041.0"
    },
    "Headers": {
    },
    "Message": {
        "nome": "TESTE 2",
        "acaoId": 2,
        "mensagem": "TESTE 2"
    },
    "MessageType": [
        "urn:message:MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Models.Commands:Proposta"
    ]
}
```

The consumer startup:

```
services.AddMassTransit<IAzureServiceBusService>(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommandHandler>();

                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.UseConcurrencyLimit(serviceBusSettings.AzureServiceBusSettings.ExemploAplicacaoPocA.ConcurrencyLimit);

                    cfg.Host("connString", h =>
                    {
                        h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(serviceBusSettings.AzureServiceBusSettings.ExemploAplicacaoPocA.OperationTimeout);
                        h.TransportType = Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                    });

                    cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
            services.AddSettings(configuration);
```

The handler:

```
namespace MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Handlers.CommandHandlers
{
    public class EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommandHandler : IConsumer<Proposta>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Proposta> context)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusFaultCommandHandler : IConsumer<Fault<EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommand>>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<EnviarExemploPocAzureServiceBusCommand>> context)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

When I send the message using MassTransit as well, the consumer works and the message is queued like:

```
{
  "messageId": "00010000-0faa-0009-6497-08d854edbfe1",
  "conversationId": "00010000-0faa-0009-3b83-08d854edbfe5",
  "sourceAddress": "sb://organization.servicebus.windows.net/XXXX",
  "destinationAddress": "sb://organization.servicebus.windows.net/topic",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:MassTransit.MultipleBus.ServiceBus.Models.Commands:Proposta"
  ],
  "message": {
    "nome": "TESTE DOIS",
    "acaoId": 2,
    "mensagem": "TESTE DOIS"
  },
  "sentTime": "2020-09-09T18:25:37.6127127Z",
  "headers": {
    "MT-Activity-Id": "|1e87ff49-4beb56732bfd4887.3."
  },
  "host": {
    "machineName": "NOTEXXXXXX",
    "processName": "iisexpress",
    "processId": 37092,
    "assembly": "MassTransit.MultipleBus",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "3.1.5",
    "massTransitVersion": "7.0.2.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19041.0"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
The namespace seems to be correct, I did everything I found about it and I can't make it work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: PascalCase vs camelCase names perhaps? It looks okay, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, the problem was the 'Content-Type' of the message. I changed it to 'application/vnd.masstransit+json' as the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html) says and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the MassTransit serializer to receive messages of any type omitting service MassTransit fields. Just add this setting to your configuration:
config.UseRawJsonSerializer(MassTransit.Serialization.RawSerializerOptions.AnyMessageType, true);