# Publish a message to the right queue of RabbitMQ from Python (Pika) for consumption in .NET (MassTransit)

Tags: python, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, pika

I want to publish a message from a Python-based microservice (using Pika) to a queue of RabbitMQ consumed by a .NET-based microservice (using MassTransit as event bus).

A sample code of the (Python-based) publisher is as follows:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters('amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2F'))

channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='queue_net', durable=True)

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='queue_net', body='message',
properties=pika.BasicProperties(
    content_type = 'text/plain',
    delivery_mode = 2 # make messages persistent
))
```

Instead of being sent to the `queue_net` queue, the message goes to a `queue_net_error` queue (from the RabbitMQ Management screen).

For completeness, a sample code of the (.NET-based) consumer is as follows:

In `Startup`, `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddConsumer<SampleConsumer>();
    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("amqp://rabbitmq:5672", h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue_net", ep =>
        {
            ep.ConfigureConsumer<SampleConsumer>(ctx);
        });
    });
});
```

where `SampleConsumer` is defined as:

```
public class SampleConsumer : IConsumer<string>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<string> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am able to do the opposite, i.e. publish from .NET and consume in Python.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a [supported message format](https://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html) and content type so that the message can be consumed by MassTransit, or you can use the raw JSON message deserializer in MassTransit to consume messages from other languages that send raw JSON.

Messages end up in the *_error* queue when the message is unable to be processed, which could be a serialization error or an exception thrown by a consumer. Messages end up in the *_skipped* queue when they are able to be deserialized but no consumer actually consumed the message (due to a mismatched message type, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, Chris. At the end I followed your 2nd suggestion, i.e. use the raw JSON message deserializer by MassTransit. A reference code can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573450/masstransit-serialize-non-masstransit-message